# An excellent free-throw shooter attempts several free throws until she misses.

Tags: probability

An excellent free-throw shooter attempts several free throws until she misses.

(a) If p = 0.9 is her probability of making a free throw, what is the probability of having the first miss on the 13th attempt or later?

For a). why is it $0.9^{12}$, I was thinking $0.9^{12}$*0.1 since she is gonna miss on the $13^{th}$ time.

Comment: “... *or later* ”

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I noticed that but how does it change the game?

Comment: The number you suggest is the probability that her first failure is on the thirteenth throw. But the probability her first failure is sometimes on ore after the thirteenth throw or later is just the odds that she makes the first 12 shots.

Comment: Another way to approach it is to think about it as "when is her first miss?" This could be on the 13th shot, the 14th shot, the 15th shot, etc... and if you write out all the probabilities for each case and add them up, you should get an infinite geometric series that leads you to the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states that the first miss attempt happens on **or** later. The presence of the "or later" signifies that there will be at least 12 makes, which is $0.9^{12}$.

Another way of thinking about it is through summing all the probabilities that the first miss occurs after the first 13 shots. This can be modeled by a geometric variable as denoted below: $$ \sum_{i=13}^\infty (0.9)^{i-1}(1-0.9) $$

Both of these methods are correct and yield the same answer its just how you think about it.